# How to get a list records in 1c from JSON data

Tags: json, 1c

I get JSON data in 1C from the address written below. There is no problem when there is only one registration. But I cannot list many records. It gives an error "Object field not found (Key)." What do I have to do to list the records? Help, please.

```
              Host     = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
          HTTPRequest = New HTTPRequest;
              // HTTPRequest.ResourceAddress = "todos/1";
               HTTPRequest.ResourceAddress = "photos/" ;// ThisObject.Attribute2;
               HTTPConnection         = New HTTPConnection(host,,,,,10,New OpenSSLSecureConnection);
               HTTPAnswer               = HTTPConnection.Get(HTTPRequest);
               stringAnswer= HTTPAnswer.GetBodyAsString();
               JSONReader = New JSONReader;
               JSONReader.SetString(stringAnswer);
               JsonResult = ReadJson(JSONReader,True);      

                For each strResult in JsonResult Do
                    If (strResult.Key = "url") Then
                        Message(strResult.Value);                                                  
                     EndIf;
               EndDo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

`Host     = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";`

`HTTPRequest = New HTTPRequest;`

`HTTPRequest.ResourceAddress = "photos/" ;`

`HTTPConnection   = New HTTPConnection(host,,,,,10,New OpenSSLSecureConnection);`

`HTTPAnswer      = HTTPConnection.Get(HTTPRequest);`

`stringAnswer   = HTTPAnswer.GetBodyAsString();`

`JSONReader       = New JSONReader;`

`JSONReader.SetString(stringAnswer);`

`JsonResult = ReadJson(JSONReader,True);`

```
  For each strResult in JsonResult Do

  For Each curElement In strResult Do 

     If (curElement.Key = "url") Then

        Message(curElement.Value);

        Break; // since the value curElement.Key = "url" can be only once, we can exit the loop

     EndIf;

  EndDo;
```

`EndDo;`
­

JsonResult is an array of values (see scr.1). Each element of the array is a map strResult (scr.2). First, in a loop, we iterate over all the elements of the array, and in a nested loop, we iterate over the matching fields.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
use curElement.get("Key")
```

it another type of data

Comment: Since this is already provided in the accepted answer, I can only assume this was posted as a "thank you" or "confirmation" comment.